# DataPower Multiple Deployment

Tags: soa, middleware, ibm-datapower

Is there any solution for multiple deployment to different dataPower appliances?
We have four of datapower appliances ( X150 and X152 ). We want import packages all these appliances with one deployment . ( Like a cluster deployment )

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be done using any scripting tool you like and the SOMA interface. I know of many using Ant scripts for it. As you have the old XI50's you can't use RMI (REST) interface as that is not supported for XI50 and firmware 6.

You should be careful though if you have different firmwares on the old XI50 and XI52's (and obviously look into replacing the XI50's as they are out-of-support since 2014)!

Have a look at the (open source) appliance-management-center as well at https://github.com/ibm-datapower/appliance-management-center which can handle deploys.
This was previously sold by IBM as the WebSphere Appliance Management Center (WAMC).

Comment: I have install appliance management center. It provides to multi firmware deployment but I need to deploy(import) configuration file( e.g. web service proxy) to multiple appliances. Appliance management center only provides single deployment(import)  for configuration files. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANT and SOMA Management. Or maybe you can try Continuous Integration with Jenkins or Urban Code Deploy.